# Where is my Record Luxus Racer bicycle from?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, vintage, germany

I just bought a bicycle on a classified ads platform in France. I don't know anything about the brand and I couldn't find much information yet.

It is a **Record Luxus Racer**, as shown on the pictures below.

I have seen other people selling bikes of the same model, in various colors and in both men's and women's versions.
Most of the pictures were found on classified ad sites from: Germany, Poland, Romania and Hungary.

However, the ads were outdated and had been removed so I couldn't get information there. Some ads were still up, but the sellers mention they don't have information about the bike's history.

The person I bought my bike from didn't know anything about it either.

My questions are:

- **Which country is this bicycle from?**
- **Does this brand still exist?**
- **Where could I find more information about my Record Luxus Racer?**

Please let me know if more pictures or information could be useful.

[image: Record - what seems to be the brand]

[image: Luxus Racer - what seems to be a model]

** the pictures aren't of my bike, but of a similar one from the Internet

**EDIT:**

Full picture of my bike.

[image: Record Luxus Racer - full bike picture]

**Record** branding on the steerer tube

[image: Record - steerer tube]

Marathon Schwalbe Spezial tires (Germany)

[image: Marathon Schwalbe Spezial]

**EDIT 2:**
*More information following some comments*

**Valves**: currently Schrader

**Front wheel rim**:

SCHURMANN - Made in W. Germany - Typ 112 steel - DIN ETRTO - 27 x 11 - 630 x 18 - 088

**Back wheel rim**:

VAN SCHOTHORST - 18 x 630 (27 x 1 174) - ?5 91 - Made in Holland

**Dynamo**:
DANSI TYP:FG8 - K10861 - 6W 3V

**Stand**:
OLONA

**Pedals**:
UNION K10490 - W. GERMANY

**Rear derailleur**
1 x 5 - SHIMANO Tourney

Comment: A picture that shows the entire bike would be helpful.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion, I have added some more pics.

Comment: Eastern Europe, probably GDR. or Czech if those are Dunlop valves and 650 wheels.

Comment: "spezial" is German for "Special", and Schwalbe started making tyres in 1973 in Korea but importing them into Germany.  Not sure which side of Germany though, and there could have been a schwalbe on either side.

Comment: I see a lugged steel frame with cottered cranks and a 1x 5(?) derailleur gear.  The rack and saddle look newer than the bike.  I'm not sure about the handle bars and stem - they are shiny chrome whereas the rest of the bike is dull galvanised, or painted.  So the bars have been replaced, perhaps from steel drops to what you have now.  The brake calipers look original, but the brake levers do not match so that backs up a bar change.

Comment: Not sure about the black plastic thing just aft of the seatpost clamp bolt.   All I'd do would be replace the brake pads, and tidy up the wire to the rear lamp, perhaps using a length of heatshrink to strap the cable to the stay more elegantly than that.  And maybe change out the yellow wheel reflectors for white clipon spoke reflectors.   Its a loverly bike - ride it well.

Comment: Strange though that the brake cables are inverted, right hand - front brake. Which is unusual for a Continental bike. Or do you live in a left roadside traffic country or have imported the bike from such?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I answered some of your questions in Edit 2. I agree, rack, comfy saddle and handlebars look newer. Plus I think the gear shift was moved from the lower tube to the handlebar. I have seen several pictures online of the same frame with drop bars. I live in France, right-hand traffic, and it seems likely that the bike is from continental Europe. The inverted brakes do surprise me when riding. Could the plastic thing under the seat be for pulling a carriage of some sort? Why do you suggest changing the wheel reflectors?

Comment: [This page](http://www.foldingcyclist.com/Klapprad-folding-bikes.html) says its a west german brand. Schwalbe is based near Köln, so I'd guess its still west german.

Comment: If the bike were first sold in the US I'd guess that it was built 1965-1978.  It's very much similar (other than the noted upgrades) to my 1973 Raleigh.  Hard to say when the same technology would have been common in eastern Europe.

Comment: The tires are almost certainly not original equipment, so they won't tell you anything.

Comment: The link provided by @Batman looks like a big step towards answering this question. "Record" and "Luxus" are both words that come up in the list of brands. "Racer" would convey that "this is not a foldable bike, this is a race/road bike". I wonder if I can find a picture of a Klapprad bearing a "Record" branding similar to the one on my bike. I'm just thinking that these brands might have a different logo for every bike model. For instance, the checkered logo on the steerer tube might only fit a "Racer" model. Any thoughts?

Comment: This question is now the top google result for keywords "luxus record bicycle"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will help you much, but I own a record bicycle, a mountain bicycle, and this brand was sold a looong time ago in my country (Mexico), I hope that the fact that it was sold in my country help you find which brand produced that bicycle :)

Comment: Do you know if it was sold new, or if it was sold second hand?  If the latter, could have moved with a household rather than being sold retail.

Answer (score 1):

Made in Luxembourg, just seen one with original sticker

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Do you think you could get a photo of that to add to your answer?

Answer (score -2):

I believe your bicycle was made buy record bicycle which is a manufacturer based in Quebec.

Unfortunately I do not know about the model "Lexus Racer"
But if you send them an email with regard to this model I am sure you will get some information regarding your bicycle, I live in France and speak french fluently so if you need any help with translation I can.
google translate doesn't always do the job .

The website For the manufacturer is: http://bicyclesrecord.com

Good luck finding any information regarding your bicycle.

Max

Comment: Note that it's Luxus, not Lexus. But welcome to the site!

Comment: Also that link appears to be a retail bike shop or LBS, not a manufacturer of any kind. They do not show any bikes branded Record.